# Calls FilterAttach in filter driver

Tags: ndis

I create  NDIS network filter driver but when I install it I see "FilterAttach" call 4 times.
Why "FilterAttach" call 4 times In my Filter Driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 reasons that you'll see many `FilterAttach` calls in your driver:

- multiple NICs,
- monitoring filters, and
- NDIS binding recalculations

Let's look at each in detail.

### Multiple NICs

Filter drivers will bind a filter module to each NIC that is compatible with the filter driver.  So if you have 3 compatible NICs, you'll get at least three calls to `FilterAttach`.

```
 [TCPIP]    [TCPIP]    [TCPIP]
    |          |          |
[filter1]  [filter2]  [filter3]
    |          |          |
 [NIC1]     [NIC2]     [NIC3]
```

You can tell you're in this situation because the `NDIS_FILTER_ATTACH_PARAMETERS::BaseMiniportIfIndex` value is different across the different `FilterAttach` instances.  This means your filter is getting bound over different NICs.

### Monitoring filters

An NDIS LWF is either **monitoring** or **modifying**.  Look in the INF file to see which type of filter you have:

```
; For a Monitoring filter, use this:
;     HKR, Ndi,FilterType,0x00010001, 1 ; Monitoring filter
; For a Modifying filter, use this:
;     HKR, Ndi,FilterType,0x00010001, 2 ; Modifying filter
```

The difference between monitoring and modifying is in how these filters bind to a network card.  A modifying filter is the simplest: it will just bind once per network card.  In contrast, monitoring filters will bind once *for each other modifying filter*, and one more time for the NIC itself.  Here's a diagram of what happens when you have a monitoring filter and 2 modifying filters:

```
  [TCPIP]
     |
[monitoring1]   // 3
     |
[modifying2]
     |
[monitoring1]   // 2
     |
[modifying1]
     |
[monitoring1]   // 1
     |
   [NIC]
```

The key thing to notice in this diagram is that the same monitoring filter is attached 3 times to the stack: once over the NIC, and once over each of the 2 modifying filters (`modifying1` and `modifying2`).

If you don't want your monitoring filter to bind at each altitude like that, you can return `NDIS_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED` from your `FilterAttach` handler any time `NDIS_FILTER_ATTACH_PARAMETERS::LowerIfIndex` is different from `NDIS_FILTER_ATTACH_PARAMETERS::BaseMiniportIfIndex`.  If you have a mandatory filter, you should also set the `NDIS_FILTER_ATTACH_FLAGS_IGNORE_MANDATORY` flag in the `NDIS_FILTER_ATTACH_PARAMETERS::Flags`, but note that we do not recommend marking a monitoring filter as mandatory.

You can tell that you're in this situation if the `NDIS_FILTER_ATTACH_PARAMETERS::BaseMiniportIfIndex` is the same in both calls to `FilterAttach`, but the NDIS_FILTER_ATTACH_PARAMETERS::FilterModuleGuidName`is different.  The`BaseMiniportIfIndex`tells you which miniport your filter is over, and the`FilterModuleGuidName` tells you exactly which filter instance is attaching.

### NDIS binding recalculations

The final reason that a filter may see multiple calls to its `FilterAttach` routine is because NDIS sometimes recalculates bindings.  Maybe a new filter is getting installed below your filter — NDIS will unbind your filter (`FilterDetach`) bind the new filter, then bind your filter again (`FilterAttach`).

You can tell that NDIS is re-trying your filter due to a binding recalculation because the `NDIS_FILTER_ATTACH_PARAMETERS::FilterModuleGuidName` is the same as a previous call to `FilterAttach`.  This means that NDIS is attaching your filter in the same spot as before.

### Debugging tips

If you have a kernel debugger attached, you can always use `!ndiskd.filterdriver` to see where your filter is attached.  You can also use `!ndiskd.netreport` to see a graphical visualization of the network stack.